# Can I tell ChromeDriverService to run as a different user?

Tags: java, scala, selenium-chromedriver

I have a webapp running on tomcat on elastic beanstalk. So the process is running as user tomcat. I would like to start a ChromeDriver from inside the app and use it to do some webscraping. I use ChromeDriverService to start my headless chrome but then because the process is running as tomcat it cannot access the chrome profile. I would like to create a user called chrome and then run the chromedriver as user chrome.

I have installed google-chrome and chromedriver on the server, and can run them fine from the command line when I am logged in as the ec2-user. The problem occurs when I try and start a chromedriver from my app.

```
Aug 30 11:45:25 ip-172-31-4-223 server: 11:45:25.551 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG ImageScan - parsing
Aug 30 11:45:25 ip-172-31-4-223 server: 11:45:25.583 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG ImageScan - user home = /usr/share/tomcat
Aug 30 11:45:25 ip-172-31-4-223 server: 11:45:25.584 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG ImageScan - user dir = /usr/share/tomcat
Aug 30 11:45:25 ip-172-31-4-223 server: 11:45:25.585 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG ImageScan - user name = tomcat
Aug 30 11:45:25 ip-172-31-4-223 server: Starting ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.87 (cd6713ebf92fa1cacc0f1a598df280093af0c5d7-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#1689}) on port 13210
Aug 30 11:45:25 ip-172-31-4-223 server: Only local connections are allowed.
Aug 30 11:45:25 ip-172-31-4-223 server: Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
Aug 30 11:45:25 ip-172-31-4-223 server: ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Aug 30 11:45:26 ip-172-31-4-223 server: 11:45:26.387 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG ImageService - Non fatal exception occurred serverside 2
Aug 30 11:45:26 ip-172-31-4-223 server: 11:45:26.392 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG ImageService - [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@1e40bc95
Aug 30 11:45:26 ip-172-31-4-223 server: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot create temp dir for user data dir
Aug 30 11:45:26 ip-172-31-4-223 server: Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
```

Is this possible? I dont see how to launch the chromedriver on demand and a different user.

I have tried specifying user-data-dir=/home/ec2-user/
and get

```
Aug 30 12:07:21 ip-172-31-4-223 server: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot create default profile directory
```